# porblem in Mod rewrite url editing

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make post title as a slug in url by mod rewrite](https://serverfault.com/questions/283359/make-post-title-as-a-slug-in-url-by-mod-rewrite)

I have a url:

```
http://www.example.com/details.php?var=100&p=99
```

I want to rewrite it as using mod rewrite

```
http://www.example.com/100/99
```

I am using following rewite_rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) $  http://www.example.com/details.php?var=$1&p=$2   [L]
```

but it is not working. If I type `http://www.example.com/100/99` it redirects to `http://www.example.com/details.php?var=100&p=99` url. 
Please help me in this issue. Thanks

Comment: i missread the question, deleting my answer

Comment: but you said that its redirecting to the correct place?!! what is the problem with the redirect?

Comment: @lbu Its being reverse redirect. I want like directory structure in url and want to get rid from perimeters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prblem in your approach is

1. `^([1-9]+)` the URI starts with `/` - your telling the rule to check for some digits without `/`
2. There could be zeros in your URL so having `1-9` will not allow you to have zero.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*) http://www.example.com/details.php?var=$1&p=$2   [L]
```

You can validate your rewrite-rule here - http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

Answer (score 1):

If it's about the **redirect**, then remove the `http://...` prefix from the target part.

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(\d+)$  details.php?var=$1&p=$2   [L]
```

Make this the first rule.

Also keep in mind that you have to adapt your application to actually generate /123/456 urls. The rewriterule only works on incoming requests, it does not alter pages.

Comment: It works but images are not showing on the page.

Comment: If the page has a new virtual URL, then the relative references stop to work. The easy workaround is to embed `<base href="/index">` in the `<head>` of your pages.

Answer (score 0):

Include 0 in the regular expression:

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$  http://www.example.com/details.php?var=$1&p=$2   [L]
```

The reverse would be:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^var=([0-9]+)\&p=([0-9]+)$ 
RewriteRule ^details\.php$ http://www.example.com/%1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: problem is still persisting.

Comment: Added the reverse of the rewrite, in case you want that instead.